# How to filter out rows based on multiple conditions in R

Tags: r

Using base R I want to filter out rows based on different conditions.
First example is a really simple one but i seem to be missing something. I want to filter out all rows in to a new DF that contain values "A" and "C". To filter out based on just one condition "A" I would use the code:

```
DF2 <- DF1 [DF1$letters == "A",]
```

This works great. But to get out both I can't seem to get the code to work. I tried:

`DF2 <- DF1 [DF1$letters == "A" & "B" ,]`

it did not work.

Second situation is slightly more complex. In this case I want to filter out all rows that contain "A" and "C" from the column "Letters" and all the rows from column "Numbers" that contain "2"

```
"Letters"   "Numbers"  "ID"
    A           10      A1
    B           2       B1
    C           15      A2
    D           7       A3
    E           32      B2
```

End up with a new DF

```
"Letters"  "Numbers"   "ID"
    A          10       A1
    B           2       B1
    C          15       A2
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `DF2 <- DF1[DF1$letters %in% c("A", "B"),]`

Comment: Thank you! :) This works great for the first example :) I was missing something simple. I just have not used %in% yet. It's my third week with R .

Answer (score 0):

I think in your description you are looking for `"OR"` insted of `"AND"`

```
subset(df, Letters %in% c('A', 'C') | Numbers == 2)

#  Letters Numbers ID
#1       A      10 A1
#2       B       2 B1
#3       C      15 A2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
      filter( Letters %in% c('A', 'C') | Numbers == 2)
```